# Order by in Linq SQL VB.NET Fail

Tags: vb.net, linq, windows-phone

when I put the `Order by` clause gives me the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The member 'ExemploDB.Aluno.Nome' has no
>   supported translation to SQL.

```
 Public Sub LoadAlunos()
    Dim alunos As List(Of Aluno)

    Using db As New AlunoDataContext
        alunos = (From aluno In db.Alunos Select aluno Order By aluno.Nome).ToList
        lstAlunos.ItemsSource = alunos
    End Using
End Sub
```

My Class Aluno:

```
<Table()>
Public Class Aluno

    <Column(IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True)> _
    Private _id As Integer
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Column()>
    Private _nome As String
    Public Property Nome() As String
        Get
            Return _nome
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _nome = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Column()>
    Private _cidade As String
    Public Property Cidade() As String
        Get
            Return _cidade
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _cidade = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Sub New(nome As String, cidade As String)
        Me.Nome = nome
        Me.Cidade = cidade
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`alunos = db.Alunos.ToList().OrderBy(Function(f) f.Nome).ToList()`

Added a `ToList()` call before the orderby.